# Php mail out to mobile / sms / text; missing from, via headers

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, when php mail() is sent to a text number (via email) i.e. 123456789@vtext.com; the from shows up as the centos apache server output email (apache@host-name.com). However, I've included the correct headers; so when the same mail() is pushed to (for example) gmail it comes and shows normal with all the correct headers / mime type / from.

Any idea?

Here's the code for the normal mail

```
$headers = "From: Alert@thedomain.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Date: ". date('r') . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 ";   
$body = "body message";
mail($userinfo->username,"thedomain",$body,$headers);
```

And the code for the mobile: (We don't use date/content type/ mime for text msgs, or else the headers shows up in the txt msg)

```
$headers = "From: Alert@thedomain.com \r\n";    
$body = "body message";
mail($userinfo->mobile,"thedomain",$body,$headers);
```

Comment: I've udpated it wit hthe new edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending with the additional `-f` flag to the mail function:

```
mail($userinfo->username,"thedomain",$body,$headers, "-ffromaddress@example.com");
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for more information on additional parameters